# Nested for loop isn't iterating

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying a K and R exercise.  The program is to compare two strings.  If the first string has any characters that are also in string 2 then it will be deleted in string1.

The goal of my compare function below is to compare every array element in the first string with every array element in the second string.  If we've got a match then we "raise a red flag" (acting as a boolean value) and we DON'T add it to the new array that will contain the edited string1.  However it seems to be ignoring the second for loop.  It only passes through on the k = 0 iteration for every i iteration.  My other issue is that based on the output (provided beneath node) it seems that s1[i] is being assigned to s2[k].  I'm guessing this takes place in the if statement but how would that be possible?  Any help anyone could provide would be very appreciated.

I used the GNU GCC compiler if it makes a difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getLength(char s[]);
char compare(char s1[], char s2[],int s1Length, int s2Length);

int main()
{
    char stringOne[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    char stringTwo[] = {'P','f','g','c','t','y','u','o','z'};
    int lengthOne;
    int lengthTwo;
    lengthOne = getLength(stringOne);
    char theResultingString[lengthOne];

    lengthTwo = getLength(stringTwo);
    compare(stringOne, stringTwo, lengthOne, lengthTwo);

    return 0;
}               //end of main.

int getLength(char s[])     //getLength gives us the length of each and every string
{
    int i=0;
    for(i = 0; s[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    }               //end for loop
    return i;
}               //end of getLength

char compare(char s1[], char s2[],int s1Length, int s2Length)
{
    int redFlagRaised = 0;      //This will be used as a boolean indicator if we have a matching element
    char toBeReturned[s1Length];
    int i;
    int k;

    for(i = 0; i<s1Length; i++) {
        printf("i is now %d\n",i);
        for(k = 0; k<s2Length; k++) {
            printf("k is now %d\n",k);

            if(s1[i] = s2[k]) {     //If at any point the s1 char being examined equals any of s2 chars then

                printf("s1[i] is %c\n",s1[i]);
                printf("s2[i] is %c\n",s2[i]);

                redFlagRaised = 1;      //we raise the red flag!
            }               //end first inner if statement

            if((k=(s2Length-1))&&(redFlagRaised = 0)) { //if we reach the end and we DON'T have a red flag then
                toBeReturned[i] = s1[i];
                printf("toBeReturned[0] is %c\n",toBeReturned[0]);
            }               //end second inner if statement


        }               //end inner for loop
        redFlagRaised = 0;      //We lower the flag again for the next inner for loop iteration

    }               //end outer for loop

    printf("The result is %c", toBeReturned[0]);
    return toBeReturned[0];
}               //end of compare
```

Output:

```
i is now 0
k is now 0
s1[i] is P
s2[i] is P
i is now 1
k is now 0
s1[i] is P
s2[i] is f
i is now 2
k is now 0
s1[i] is P
s2[i] is g
i is now 3
k is now 0
s1[i] is P
s2[i] is c
i is now 4
k is now 0
s1[i] is P
s2[i] is t
i is now 5   
k is now 0
s1[i] is P
s2[i] is y
The result is �
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.005 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Comment: could you properly format this please?

Comment: Usage of `toBeReturned[]` is questionable - needs review.

Answer (score 3):

```
char stringOne[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
char stringTwo[] = {'P','f','g','c','t','y','u','o','z'};
```

These are not strings. You need to terminate them using `null character`.
Try this -

```
 char stringOne[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
 char stringTwo[] = {'P','f','g','c','t','y','u','o','z','\0'};
```

Also in this condition-

```
if(s1[i] = s2[k])
```

use `==` instead of `=`(this is assignment operator).So condition should be written as -

```
if(s1[i]==s2[k])
```

Similarly in this condition (as mentioned by Weather Vane Sir in comment)`if((k=(s2Length-1))&&(redFlagRaised = 0))` use `==`

```
 if((k==(s2Length-1))&&(redFlagRaised == 0))
```

Comment: Similarly here: `if((k=(s2Length-1))&&(redFlagRaised = 0))` using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: @WeatherVane I did it Sir. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @theBigDream instead of writing `char stringOne[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};`  you can write `char stringOne[] = "abcde";`, which is exactly the same but more readable.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Oh I didn't know that, that is a lot better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**In compare function in IF condition you are assigning the value to K like bleow**

```
if((k=(s2Length-1))&&(redFlagRaised = 0)){  //if we reach the end and we DON'T have a red flag then
toBeReturned[i] = s1[i];
printf("toBeReturned[0] is %c\n",toBeReturned[0]);
}
```

**But it's needs to be like this**

```
if((k==(s2Length-1))&&(redFlagRaised == 0)){  //if we reach the end and we DON'T have a red flag then
toBeReturned[i] = s1[i];
printf("toBeReturned[0] is %c\n",toBeReturned[0]);
}
```

**You have to use Compare operator (==) not assignment operator(=)**

**In below code**

```
char stringOne[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
char stringTwo[] = {'P','f','g','c','t','y','u','o','z'};
```

These are not strings. You need to terminate them using null character. Try this -

```
 char stringOne[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
 char stringTwo[] = {'P','f','g','c','t','y','u','o','z','\0'};
```

**Below also use this == operator instead of = operator**

```
if(s1[i] = s2[k])
```